# Tooltip placed on elements inside <script> tag looks different compared to tooltip placed on regular html elements in <body>

Tags: javascript, html, css, tooltip

I need to display tooltips on various elements in my html page.
The  element is inside  tag and the  has been declared inside 
When I display tooltips on both elements using data-toggle="tooltip", Tooltips appear with titles as specified but the tooltip for  appears in a plain box like white background whereas tooltip for  appears like default tooltip.
I tried data-container="body" but it didn't help.
What am I doing [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBTDc.png)wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Hooray!">Add All the recommended js and css files</a>
```

Welcome to SO Add All the recommended js and CSS files mate...

Comment: @Mili Dubey please upvote if you get the answer thankyou...!